# dagger java, how to the scope inherit in extends interface

Tags: java, inheritance, dagger-2

```
@ScopeClient
@Component
public interface ApiComponent {
}

@Component(modules = {ApiUserPresenterModule.class}, dependencies = ApiComponent.class)
public interface ApiUserComponent extends ApiComponent {
    void inject(LogonPresenter apiLogonPresenter);
    void inject(ProfilePresenter apiProfilePresenter);
    void inject(UserPresenter apiUserPresenter);
}
```

if adding scope in ApiUserPresenterModule

```
@Module
public class ApiUserPresenterModule {
@Provides
@ScopeClient
LogonModel provideLogonModel() {
    return new LogonModelImpl();
}

@Provides
@ScopeClient
ProfileModel provideProfileModel() {
    return new ProfileModelImpl();
}
```

}

I get an error message:
Error:(24, 1) error: example.component.ApiUserComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@example.apidata.common.scopes.ScopeClient example.component.ApiComponent

if i add Scope in component:

```
@Component(modules = {ApiUserPresenterModule.class}, dependencies = ApiComponent.class)
@ScopeClient
public interface ApiUserComponent extends ApiComponent {
    void inject(LogonPresenter apiLogonPresenter);
    void inject(ProfilePresenter apiProfilePresenter);
    void inject(UserPresenter apiUserPresenter);
}
```

i get another error message:

> Error:(24, 1) error: example.component.ApiUserComponent depends on scoped components in a non-hierarchical scope ordering:
>   @example.apidata.common.scopes.ScopeClient example.component.ApiComponent
>   @example.common.scopes.ScopeClient example.component.ApiUserComponent

How to add Scope in inherited module?

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to do it this way, but you should definitely have a look at `@SubComponent`. This is probably what you are trying to achieve with component dependencies.

Comment: sorry for my English, it's is not my speaking language. My question is "How can i use "Scope" from parent class  in to child class"

Comment: i want to use @Component's instead of your solution. How can i do it.